# Can Apple Pay be used with apps signed with an enterprise provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, applepay

How do I enable Apple Pay on a App id and also create a merchant identifier to work in Apple Pay sandbox environment using an enterprise Apple developer profile?

I could do a successful Apple Pay authorization using a App Store Apple development account. The discontinue here is with the enterprise Apple account. It’s not clearly outlined in Apple Pay programming guide that the feature isn’t available for enterprise accounts. I was comparing the App Store account with the enterprise account and found out that many Apple Pay features aren’t available in the enterprise account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app purchase is not available on `enterprise Apple account`. You add member of `enterprise Apple account` , then member account implements In app purchase.
you also:-

When the need of Apple Pay is the highest, distribute with Apple Pay through App Store account with adhoc distribution profile.
When the need for Enterprise distribution is the highest, distribute through the Enterprise account with adhoc distribution profile, and with Apple Pay Stubs 
https://github.com/stripe/ApplePayStubs from Stripe.